# php variable $a contains variable $b in it update $b and $a should automatically update

Tags: php, variables

I have two variables in PHP, say `$a` and `$b`. `$a` is a string variable. It contains `$b`. I want to update `$a` automatically if `$b` is updated.

```
$b = 4;
$a = "value is ".$b;
echo $a; // value is 4

$b = 5;
echo $a; // should print value is 5
```

Comment: What's the use case? Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$a` can be updated automatically if you assign `$b` to `$a` by reference, but there should not be any string concatenation assigned to `$a`.

Try:

```
$b = 4;
$a = &$b;
$c = 'Value is ';

echo $c.$a;

$b = 5;
echo $c.$a;
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://codepad.org/vz0FU6Im)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible the way you want it. You see, variables can be passed by reference, like so:

```
$a = &$b;
```

Which will cause `$a` to automatically update when `$b` changes, however, it may not contain any other value, (like the string you want), so you'll have to use a **function** or **another variable** to do it.

```
$b = &$a;
echo "Value is $b";
```

or

```
$b = &$a;
$description = "Value is ";
echo $description . $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have that feature. Related features you could use are:

1. [References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), which let you alias one variable to another. The value of each variable is the same, since they're simply symbol table aliases.

   ```
   $b = "I'm b."
   $a =& $b;
   echo $a;
   ```
2. [Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), in which one variable holds the name of the other.

   ```
   $b = "I'm b."
   $a = 'b';
   echo $$a;
   ```

   However, variable variables should generally be avoided as they generally cause needless obfuscation.
3. Functions (as mithunsatheesh suggests). This is closest to what you want, as a function call is an expression that will have the value you're looking for. The only place a function wouldn't work where a variable would is when interpolating the value into a [double-quoted](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.syntax.double) string or a [heredoc](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Instead, you'd have to use string concatenation, or assign the result of the function call to a local variable and interpolate that.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it by reference. How to do it ?

Make a function:

```
function showValue(&$b)
{

   return 'value is ' . $b;

}

echo showValue($b);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: actually I have a string variable which depends upon a number of other variables. So I want to update this variable if any of the other variables updates. Thanks for your valuable replies. I think I should go with function...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

```
$a = 4;
$b =& $a;
$a = 5;
echo $b; // should print 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

When a php script runs it runs "line after line". When you assign like this

```
$b = 4;
$a = "value is ".$b;
```

Value of $b is already assigned to $a as a integer 4 (not $b). So, if next `$b` is updated to some other value. Variable `$a` has no idea about it.

In this kind of case you have to use function or variable reference as describe in some other answers

```
   $a = 4;
    $b =& $a;
    $a = 5;
    echo $b;
```